# Chrome Mobile Render tool not rendering dropdowns

Tags: html, google-chrome

When I open Developer tools and turn on device mode, and click any drop down on the page chrome renders options with minimum width and rest of the area as black.

I dont know what is causing this error. I tried to update my graphics card driver, but problem still exists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, got to know that this is an issue in Chrome browser itself. Refer the following link for more info - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=553274&q=status%3Aunconfirmed&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&num=1000

Comment: @Mehmet, This issue is fixed in latest chrome version 49x.. Please check out